# How do I remove the height style from a DIV using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout

By default, a DIV's height is determined by its contents.

But, I override that and explicitly set a height with jQuery:

```
$('div#someDiv').height(someNumberOfPixels);
```

How can I reverse that?  I want to remove the height style and to make it go back to it's automatic/natural height?

Comment: I can't get this to work either. It seems that after you set the height of the div to something specific (like 300px or whatever), you can't set the height back to auto. Might be a jQuery bug.

Answer (score 114):

to remove the height:

```
$('div#someDiv').css('height', '');
$('div#someDiv').css('height', null);
```

like John pointed out, set height to `auto`:

```
$('div#someDiv').css('height', 'auto');
```

(checked with jQuery 1.4)

Comment: You gave three solutions, I can confirm setting height to "" works, don't know about the others.

Comment: In jQuery 1.9 using '' but using `null` does not.

Comment: There are subtle differces: 1+2 lets revices thew stlyesheet (if anything is defined there), 3 overrides it (as the attrib set to auto has higher precedence)

Answer (score 26):

```
$('div#someDiv').height('auto');
```

I like using this, because it's symmetric with how you explicitly used .height(val) to set it in the first place, and works across browsers.

Comment: This forces the height to be the auto height, overriding any existing CSS rules. That may be OK in some specific instances, but in general it could cause problems.

Comment: @BennettMcElwee I'm actually struggling with the issue you described now. So +1 for that.

Answer (score 24):

you can try this:

```
$('div#someDiv').height('');
```

Comment: that should be correct anwser as this one removes css() style value, it is usefull on resizing with js :) Cheers, thanks

Answer (score 21):

maybe something like

```
$('div#someDiv').css("height", "auto");
```

Comment: That will override any existing CSS rules that should apply, which may be a problem.

Answer (score 14):

To reset the height of the div, just try

`$("#someDiv").height('auto');`

Comment: This is a duplicate of @nonrectangular's answer, which predates this edit.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('div#someDiv').css('height', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add to the answers here, I was using the height as a function with two options either specify the height if it is less than the window height, or set it back to auto

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
$('div#someDiv').height(function(){
    if ($(this).height() < windowHeight)
        return windowHeight;
    return 'auto';
});
```

I needed to center the content vertically if it was smaller than the window height or else let it scroll naturally so this is what I came up with

Answer (score 0):

Thank guys for showing all those examples. I was **still** having trouble with my contact page on small media screens like below 480px after trying your examples. Bootstrap kept inserting `height: auto`.

Element Inspector / Devtools will show the height in:

```
element.style {

}
```

In my case I was seeing: `section#contact.contact-container | 303 x 743` in the browser window.

So the following full-length works to eliminate the issue:

`$('section#contact.contact-container').height('');`

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `unset`

```
$('some-element').css('height', 'unset');
```

You may refer to this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset#:%7E:text=The%20unset%20CSS%20keyword%20resets,its%20initial%20value%20if%20not.)

Answer (score -6):

```
$('div#someDiv').removeAttr("height");
```

Comment: i don't think this will work for a css height style that is embedded within a a style attribute...

Comment: If anything, you'd want to removeAttr("style")

Comment: This does work and is the best option however if (unlike the question here) you're trying to remove a `height="XX"` HTML attribute