# JQuery and Inline & External CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I know the following JQuery will remove an attribute from an image tag

```
$('img').removeAttr('height');
```

in

```
<img src="images/abc.jpg" alt="Image 1" height="30px" width="30px" />
```

But how can I do the same if the img tag in in the following format?

```
<img src="images/abc.jpg" alt="Image 1" style="height:30px; width:30px;" />
```

Also how to do the same if the CSS in in an external file

```
<img src="images/abc.jpg" alt="Image 1" class="imgclass1" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/804161/552792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
$('img').css('height', '');
```

jQuery will remove the `height` style from the element

> removes that property from an element if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style attribute