# Setting div height 100% that is floating inside another div

Tags: css, html, height, css-float, parent

How would I setup a div to be 100% of the parent div if it is floating?

Here are the two styles I've got, where sidebar is the child of container -

```
#container {
    width:1200px;
    margin-top:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
#sidebar {
    width:260px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:1554px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get equal height columns?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with Javascript or better said jQuery.
Have a look here: [How do I keep multiple DIVs the same height using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803688/how-do-i-keep-multiple-divs-the-same-height-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Elements that contain only floated children have a height that collapses to 0. So if you want to set the height of a child to 100% of the parent, you need to manually set the height on the parent.